# extending jquery 1.2 to include index()

Tags: jquery, indexing, extend

I'm working with some 3rd party teams and am unable to upgrade to jquery 1.4+ and therfor stuck with 1.2. I was wondering if there was a way to extend the library to include the index() method. I tried writing a quick function but had no luck.

```
function getIndex( $elm ) {
    var $this = $elm;
    var $parent = $elm.parent();
    var $index = 0;
    $parent.children().each(function(){
        if( $this.length == $(this).length && $this.length == $this.filter($(this)).length ) {
            return $index;
        }else{
            $index++;   
        }
    });
    return $index;
}
```

ANy help much appreciated.

regards

Phil

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/traversing.js#L137

Comment: What you may want to do it to introduce the latest version of jQuery in `noConflict()` mode, and slowly move things over to that version...

Answer (score 1):

Ah, found the method and added it in!

```
$.fn.index = function(elem){
    // No argument, return index in parent
    if ( !elem ) {
        return ( this[0] && this[0].parentNode ) ? this.prevAll().length : -1;
    }
    // index in selector
    if ( typeof elem === "string" ) {
        return jQuery.inArray( this[0], jQuery( elem ) );
    }
    // Locate the position of the desired element
    return jQuery.inArray(
        // If it receives a jQuery object, the first element is used
        elem.jquery ? elem[0] : elem, this );
}
```

Comment: Just a humble note - I also mentioned it in the comment :-)